# AngularJS slide right / left animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to create a simple slide animation with AngularJS.

I have a feedback tab that when someone click on it it will slide from right to left and will open, another click will do the animation again and will close it.

The thing is i'm not sure how to create the slide animation.

I read about that that **ng-animation** is obsolete and now i need to use class and it automatically hook on **ng-hide** and **ng-show**

I have 2 div elements:

```
<div class="feedback-close" data-ng-hide="feedback_open" data-ng-click="feedback_open = !feedback_open"></div>

<div class="feedback-open" data-ng-show="feedback_open" data-ng-click="feedback_open = !feedback_open"></div>
```

i need some code that will make the slide animation from close to open and from open to close.

can anyone help me out ?

a nice slide example will be in here : http://feedback-me.appspot.com/example_bootstrap.html

Comment: Are you talking about the core angular [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module? Where did you read that was obsolete?

Comment: @RobJ i didn't mean ngAnimate is obsolete but the directive ng-animation is obsolete.

Comment: The ngAnimate module can do what you're looking for.

Comment: @RobJ can you write a simple example?

Comment: The angular docs have a pretty good example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations).